# wrap md-list-item in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

why i can't wrap an md-list-item in a custom directive ?

## Original html

```
 <md-list class="md-dense">
        <md-list-item  ng-repeat="user in items"> 
            <img ng-src="{{user.img}}" class="md-avatar"/>
            <span flex>{{user.code}}</span>
            <span flex>{{user.date}}</span>
            <span flex>{{user.destination}}</span>
            <md-divider inset></md-divider>
        </md-list-item>
 </md-list>
```

and the result is

[image]

## Directive my-user

### Directive consumer

```
<md-list class="md-dense">
    <md-list-item  ng-repeat="user in items"> 
       <my-user ng-model=user></my-user>
       <md-divider inset></md-divider>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

### my_user.directive.js

```
angular.module("monitorApp")
.directive('myUser',[function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            ngModel:'='
        },
        templateUrl:'/src/my_user.html',
        link:function(scope){
            scope.$watch('ngModel',function(){
                scope.user = scope.ngModel ? scope.ngModel : {};
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

### directive template my_user.html

```
<div>
  <img ng-src="{{user.img}}" class="md-avatar"/>
  <span flex>{{user.code}}</span>
  <span flex>{{user.date}}</span>
  <span flex>{{user.destination}}</span>
</div>
```

will result in

[image]

As yuo can see the items are not rendered right.
Maybe because using the directive the md-list-item are not directly child of md-list but they are wrapped by the directive tag and the div tag.
I tried to use the replace:true in my directive or use the directive with restricted:'A' but without success.

Hope can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `md-list-item` to your directive template - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/gLMYzW?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-list class="md-dense">
    <my-user ng-repeat="user in items" ng-model=user></my-user>
    <md-divider inset></md-divider>
  </md-list>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="my_user.html">
    <md-list-item>
      <img ng-src="{{user.img}}" class="md-avatar"/>
      <span flex>{{user.code}}</span>
      <span flex>{{user.date}}</span>
      <span flex>{{user.destination}}</span>
    </md-list-item>
  </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

  .directive('myUser',[function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{
        ngModel:'='
      },
      templateUrl:'my_user.html',
      link:function(scope){
        scope.$watch('ngModel',function(){
          scope.user = scope.ngModel ? scope.ngModel : {};
        });
      }
    };
  }])

  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {code: 1, date: "14/11/16", destination: "Camden"},
      {code: 2, date: "14/11/16", destination: "Camden"},
      {code: 3, date: "14/11/16", destination: "Camden"}
    ];
  });
```